# MockMvc testing : jsonPath, test every element returned contains substring

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, jsonpath, mockmvc

I'm doing an integration test, and the returned value is an array of json objects. The following line of code matches without error:

```
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(uri)
            .param("name", text)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$[0].name", Matchers.containsString("div3")));
```

but when I change `$[0].name` to `$[*].name` I get an error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$[*].name"
Expected: a string containing "div3"
 but: was a net.minidev.json.JSONArray (<["Testing Custom Searches div3: 1","Testing Custom Searches div3: 4","Testing Custom Searches div3: 7","Testing Custom Searches div3: 10","Testing Custom Searches div3: 13","Testing Custom Searches div3: 16","Testing Custom Searches div3: 19"]>)
```

I've been searching around, and not finding an answer...is there a way to check that every *.name element contains a given substring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `Matchers.containsString()` expect a `String` input but `$[*].name` returns a `net.minidev.json.JSONArray` which is an `ArrayList`.

You can use `Matchers.everyItem` to match against a list:

```java
MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$[*].name", Matchers.everyItem(Matchers.containsString("div3")))
```

Comment: How could we match to a json object?

Comment: @MauricioToledo you might consider using a library for that, for example JSONAssert